# A variable value changes while simple I/O with 2D array in C resulting in segmentation fault

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

First of all, please excuse me, I'm a beginner. I'm just trying to get the dimension n of a square and fill up a 2D array with values 1 to n^2. This is what I coded:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int dimension = 0;
printf("Enter the size: ");
scanf("%d", &dimension);

int square[dimension][dimension];
int count = 1;
int i, j;

printf("\n%d dimension", dimension);

for(i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
    for(j = 0; i < dimension; j++){
        square[i][j] = count;
        count++;
    }
}

printf("\n%d dimension\n", dimension);

for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
            printf("%d ",square[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

And I get the following output for an input of 3:

```
Enter the size: 
3 dimension
31 dimension
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 34 34 33 
7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 34 34 33 2 29 2 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 34 34 33 3 26 2 0 2 0 
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 34 34 33 4 23 2 0 2 0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 34 34 33 5 20 2 0 2 0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 34 34 33 6 17 2 0 2 0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 0 0 4195664 
22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 34 34 33 7 14 2 0 2 0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 34 34 33 8 11 2 0 2 0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 
28 29 30 31 34 34 33 9 8 2 0 2 0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 4196560 0 
31 34 34 33 10 5 2 0 2 0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 4196560 0 1548250007 32550 1 
33 11 2 2 0 2 0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 4196560 0 1548250007 32550 1 0 -372175928 32765 
2 0 2 0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 4196560 0 1548250007 32550 1 0 -372175928 32765 32768 1 4195910 
0 -372176384 32765 1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 4196560 0 1548250007 32550 1 0 -372175928 32765 32768 1 4195910 0 0 0 
1443246592 1101415723 1552312736 32550 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 4196560 0 1548250007 32550 1 0 -372175928 32765 32768 1 4195910 0 0 0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 
32550 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 4196560 0 1548250007 32550 1 0 -372175928 32765 32768 1 4195910 0 0 0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 
4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 4196560 0 1548250007 32550 1 0 -372175928 32765 32768 1 4195910 0 0 0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 
32765 0 0 0 0 4196560 0 1548250007 32550 1 0 -372175928 32765 32768 1 4195910 0 0 0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 1292031905 -230216595 
0 0 4196560 0 1548250007 32550 1 0 -372175928 32765 32768 1 4195910 0 0 0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 1292031905 -230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 
0 1548250007 32550 1 0 -372175928 32765 32768 1 4195910 0 0 0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 1292031905 -230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 32765 0 0 
1 0 -372175928 32765 32768 1 4195910 0 0 0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 1292031905 -230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 32765 0 0 0 0 1552312115 
32765 32768 1 4195910 0 0 0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 1292031905 -230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 32765 0 0 0 0 1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 
4195910 0 0 0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 1292031905 -230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 32765 0 0 0 0 1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 441844 0 0 
0 1229117345 230489935 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 1292031905 -230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 32765 0 0 0 0 1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 441844 0 0 0 0 0 
4195664 0 -372175936 32765 0 0 0 0 1292031905 -230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 32765 0 0 0 0 1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 441844 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4195664 
32765 0 0 0 0 1292031905 -230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 32765 0 0 0 0 1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 441844 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 
0 0 1292031905 -230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 32765 0 0 0 0 1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 441844 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 4195705 0 -372175944 
-230216595 -1904420959 -202356897 0 32765 0 0 0 0 1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 441844 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 4195705 0 -372175944 32765 28 0 
0 32765 0 0 0 0 1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 441844 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 4195705 0 -372175944 32765 28 0 1 0 -372170838 
0 0 0 1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 441844 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 4195705 0 -372175944 32765 28 0 1 0 -372170838 32765 0 0 
1552312115 32550 1552205368 32550 441844 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4195664 0 -372175936 32765 4195705 0 -372175944 32765 28 0 1 0 -372170838 32765 0 0 0 0 33
```

No matter what input I give, the value of dimension changes in between. This is what I get on an online IDE. On my terminal run in ubuntu, it says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". As someone who is familiar with Python, I find it very hard to cope up with C's rules. How do I solve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: in the loop where you assign count, your second for loop should be j < dimensions

Comment: Your first set of nested loops uses the wrong condition for the inner loop. Is this a transcription error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in second loop the check condition is wrong.

You have -

```
for(j = 0; i < dimension; j++)
```

instead of

```
for(j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
```

For say `i` value 0, the `i < dimension` is always true and the `j` value increments without any restriction. So, when you try to access `square[i][j]` the value of `j` may be very much bigger than `dimension` and that is invalid memory access which lead to the segmentation fault

Comment: Omg, I'm that ignorant. Thank you! But changing it changes values too?

Comment: @Coffee3 No, you aren´t. Mistakes like that can happen to everyone. :-)

Comment: @Coffee3, as RobertS said mistakes can happen. But I suggest that you learn to use debuggers like gdb. It will always be helpful